# data transfer between an android and an ios device

Tags: android, ios, p2p

I want to transfer some data (app specific data) from an ios device to the android device (and vice versa) running the same application for respective platform. 
I understand the easiest way to achieve this is to have a relay server which will take data from one device and pass it on to the other. 
However, i would prefer if this could be achieved on a wifi network (peer to peer) without using any kind of server in between (the way they do in multiplayer games).

I tried gamekit but its supposed to work only on ios devices and cant support android. Tried alljoyn as well but its not available for ios yet.

Anyone who has tried this or has some idea on how to proceed are most welcome with their thoughts....

Comment: What comes to mind is just opening up a socket connection and sending JSON data back and forth. One device has to always know the IP adress of the other device though. 
What kind of app is it for and what kind of data is being exchanged?

Comment: This is something that popped up in my mind too.. but i am not sure how do i broadcast a device's(ios or android) ip running my application. Are you aware of a library or something which does that?? Basically what i am trying to achieve here is what gamekit does in ios but i want it to support android as well. The data i will be transferring is app specific metadata (some numbers and dictionaries probably) which should be easily transferable with JSON serialization.

Comment: I cannot think about a way. I would still recommend you write up some very simple java server that runs within the local network (with a known IP), just let the 2 clients exchange their IPs via that server, then they can connect directly to each other.

Comment: I dont see that as an option because i cant have my server running for all the local/ad hoc wifi networks in this world.
What i want is 2 devices connecting to same network just somehow see other by broadcasting their presence, connect to the other and start talking... Looks simple in theory but i cant find a way to do it !!

Comment: I see... so whats the use case for your app? A game that two players play within one network? If thats the case, you can request your users to come close to each other and make a short bluetooth connection perhaps?

EDIT: Why cant you have your server running for all networks? Just put in on some server on the internet and let clients exchange their local IPs. They'll have internet access anyway when theyre connected to a network.

Comment: Exactly.. something like a multiplayer game does. Even if users sit next to each other, i dont think ios allows you to transfer data through bluetooth (except with gamekit ofcourse in which you will need other device to be ios as well).
To answer your question on server.. I am not very keen on taking the pain of hosting something this small on a public server. Just doesn't seems worth the trouble. Also, i want the users to be able to connect even in absence of internet connectivity (just using adhoc local wifi network)

Comment: You could try how much time it takes for one device to try to connect to one IP (unknown host should return pretty quickly). If you can do ~5-10 IPs per second, you can try all local IPs (256) within a bearable amount of time. Should be half if both clients try.

Comment: Found any solution for this, if yes please share.

Answer (score 0):

I don't ever try that.... but may be you can do that using XML file...
so

1. Make the XML file of data which you want to send...
2. Send that file using bluetooth or using wi-fi programatically...
3. On another device you can fetch data from xml file..

and that's how you can make this happen....

Comment: point no 2 is exactly my question... how do i achieve that while being platform independent i.e. support android and ios both !!

Comment: @venkat have you found any way to exchange data?